# "This article will discuss / discusses"

Tags: future

I would like if someone can help me with following

"This article will discuss revaluation".

I saw this title on a paper article and I really want to know why they used "will" here instead of using present simple.

Comment: Merely a style choice. They're inviting you into the discussion (although you won't be given much opportunity to disagree).

Comment: Well, for one, at that point the article hasn't discussed anything yet. The discussion is still very much in your future. For two, "will" is technically in the present tense. It does not have a future tense form.

Comment: Since the introduction is the last thing you should write, by the time you write it you use simple present because the article is finished. Then you can say what it **does** discuss, instead of predicting what you think you'll get around to discussing.

Comment: I bet a native English speaker would use The Present Simple in this case. The article is apparently written by a non-native English speaker in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Using "will discuss" is like a "promise" to discuss revaluation. It is like saying "I will return," and you can see the promise element of using *future will*. As such, the sentence informs the reader what to expect the article to do (in the future, as she/he continues to read).

Comment: "I will return" and there is a great possibility that it's not for sure and may not happen at all. And a published article already contains some facts without promises.

Comment: Nonsense. It’s just academic style. Take your pick.